# Usort on object returns wrong order

Tags: php

I need to modify an array of objects, based on a "custom_sorting" value. I use usort like this:

```
usort($this->rows, function($a, $b) {
    return $a->custom_sorting <=> $b->custom_sorting;
});
```

However, the returned sort order is a bit off, as can be seen in the example order below. Notice 4 comes after 39, so it treats 4 as a higher value than 39. Same goes for 5,6,7,8,9 - all treated as higher values than 45. What can I do to sort it in the correct numeric order?

```
5-37
5-38
5-39
5-4
5-40
5-41
5-42
5-43
5-44
5-45
5-5
5-7
5-8
5-9
```

Thanks

Comment: I would guess they are stored as strings and you want to compare numbers.

Comment: They're perfectly sorted *lexicographically*. You might want to consider a *natsort* to sort them numerically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Nigel Ren's comment suggests, your `custom_sorting` is probably based on string, so it's working as it should. Instead try:

Newer answer using the built in [strnatcmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php):

```php
usort($this->rows, function($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp($a->custom_sorting, $b->custom_sorting);
});
```

Older, more manual answer:

```php
usort($this->rows, function($a, $b) {
    $aDash = strpos($a->custom_sorting, '-');
    $bDash = strpos($b->custom_sorting, '-');
    $compareFirstPart = ((int) substr($a->custom_sorting, 0, $aDash-1)) <=> ((int) substr($b->custom_sorting, 0, $bDash-1));
    if ($compareFirstPart !== 0) {
        return $compareFirstPart;
    }
    return ((int) substr($a->custom_sorting, $aDash)) <=> ((int) substr($b->custom_sorting, $bDash));
});
```

Explanation:
Take the parts before the dash ('-'), cast them to ints, and comare them as ints.
If they are equal the result is 0, so return the result for the same comparison with the part after the dash;